# Embedding onto adjunction space

Tags: general-topology, closed-map

Let X and Y be topological spaces. Let A $\subset$ X be a closed set and $f : A \to Y$ a continuous map. Prove that the canonical map $Y \to Y \cup _fX$ is an embedding onto a closed subspace.

$Y \cup _fX$ denotes the adjunction space.

What do I exactly have to prove as I don't quite understand the concept of an embedding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Prove that the canonical map $Y \to Y \cup _fX$ is an embedding onto a closed subspace.

Denote this map by $g$. You have to prove the following:

- the map $g$ is injective;
- the map $g$ is continuous;
- the inverse map $g^{-1}:f(Y)\to Y$ is continuous;
- the image $g(Y)$ is closed in $Y \cup _fX$.